# How do I set up the Rating Control from the Ajax Control Toolkit?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to set up the Rating control from the Ajax Control Toolkit in a .NET 2010 app. I'm not trying to do anything fancy. Just configure it to the minimum. I an't seem to find any documentation on how to ge this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fine [Creating a Rating Control tutorial](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/creating-a-rating-control-cs) on the ASP.NET site. I think it covers everything you'll need to know. Best of luck.